# Azure AD B2C ignores custom HTML page content

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a custom HTML file set up for B2C's sign in / sign up user flow that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sign_up.css">
    <title>My Sign up</title>
</head>
<body>    
<div id="api">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've hosted this in my web app service and placed the url into the Custom Page URI field in the flow. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVEz4.jpg).

However, when I hit "Run User Flow" the default Microsoft `selfAsserted` page is still loaded. Is there anything that would cause this to happen?

To clarify: I have hit save after entering the URI and the Custom Page column says "Yes" for Local account sign up page.

Comment: Hi Eric. Did you click "Save" before running the user flow?

Comment: Hey Chris, yes I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a CORS issue. Adding `https://<resourcegroup>.b2clogin.com` to my app service's CORS whitelist resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should check again, make sure the custom page status is **Yes**. But in your screenshot, the status is **No** for the custom page.

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately the same issue occurs after doing this.